# android use java vs linux

Tags: java, android, linux

Is there any advantage/disadvantage of executing a linux command in an android app rather than using the java alternative?

ex:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
file.delete();
```

vs

```
rm file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Advantages?

None, really, or at least not in the general case.

*I could see it as being useful if you want to invoke a separate and **complex** program that doesn't expose a programmatic interface. However in that case I'd still go with invoking via `ProcessBuilder` rather than using a system execution.*

### Disadvantages

- **unsafe**

  If it's not your program, you don't know what it does. It may be tampered with, and it may require using different permissions and privileges.
- **unstable**

  If it's not your program, you don't really know if it's there and if it always will be.
- **wasteful**

  It spawns an extra process for no good reason.
- **opaque**

  It's harder for you to monitor a long-running task and to check for return codes (and again the conventions for these may change in the future, which brings us back to **unsafe** and **unstable**).

Comment: the advantage i am looking for is shorter cleaner code for some complicated tasks that have a linux function for them but to write in java would be tedious. But I see your point.

Comment: If you are very much concerned about the (arguable) clarity or simplicity of the code, then may I suggest the one-liner: `new File("file.txt").delete()`, or to look at using another language layer on top of Java in your Android app (for instance, using Groovy, Xtend or Scala), though these will imply probably another library to be packaged with the app (or a re-transcription at the source level).